# Within RealityKit, how can I make the world without friction?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I want to make the physics world without friction and damping.

I tried to make the scene's gravity to (0,0,0), and make a square and ball, give force when tapping. I want to make the ball move eternally, but it just stop in some time.

How can I make the entities friction to zero?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a new `Physics Material` to your model entity.

For this use `generate(friction:restitution:)` [type method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/physicsmaterialresource/3244780-generate):

```
static func generate(friction: Float = 0, 
                  restitution: Float = 0) -> PhysicsMaterialResource
```

where

```
/*   the coefficient of friction is in the range [0, infinity]   */

/*   and the coefficient of restitution is in the range [0, 1]   */
```

Here's a code:

```
arView.environment.background = .color(.darkGray)

let mesh = MeshResource.generateSphere(radius: 0.5)
let material = SimpleMaterial()
let model = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh,
                   materials: [material]) as (ModelEntity & HasPhysics)
    
let physicsResource: PhysicsMaterialResource = .generate(friction: 0, 
                                                      restitution: 0)
    
model.components[PhysicsBodyComponent] = PhysicsBodyComponent(
                                        shapes: [.generateSphere(radius: 0.51)],
                                          mass: 20,         // in kilograms
                                      material: physicsResource, 
                                          mode: .dynamic)

model.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)

let anchor = AnchorEntity()
anchor.addChild(model)
arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
```

P.S. Due to some imperfectness of physics engine in RealityKit, I suppose there's no possibility to create an eternal bouncing. Seemingly next RealityKit's update will fix physics engine imperfectness.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion. It did improved what i was trying to do, but the wall eventually stop, after 3~4 seconds of bumping with walls. Do you know why this happens? I set the walls and ball.

Comment: Share your code, please. Via GitHub or any file sharing service.

Comment: Please share `.rcproject` scene via https://dropmefiles.com

Comment: funny thing is that every time I try, number of bumps changes. I cannot find any patterns.

Comment: All I have to say about your amazing scene with frame and bouncing ball – it's physics (a.k.a. dynamics), it behaves approximately the same way as it should in real world situation. And, of course, as it is virtual – some bugs are possible. I think there's no possibility to have a perpetual motion in RealityKit 2.0.

Comment: I guess it's because of memory management. during it's moves, I added more balls on the scene, then it's total momentum maintained. It looks like if there is no changes on the scene, framework intentionally shut it down.

Comment: Totally agree with you.